# Google Donut Chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, donut-chart

I ran into the problem of implementing graphics via google chart, it is necessary to make a three sectional diagram, please tell me how to do it better.

[image]

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Effort', 'Amount given'],
          ['My all',     100],
          ['My alsl',     100],
          ['My alsl',     100],
        ]);

        var options = {
          pieHole: 0.85,
          tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },
          pieSliceText: 'none',
          
          pieSliceTextStyle: {
            color: 'transparent',
          },
          legend: 'none',
          slices: {
            0: { color: '#f9b231' },
            1: { color: '#7e430f' },
            2: { color: '#f8d597' }
          }
        };

 



        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donut_single'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="donut_single" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/db3kaeht/4/

Comment: You really need javascript for this? Sounds like this could be loaded like an image? You would need a javascript library if the data would change often or if you would load it from the database. Sorry if this isn't helpful but since your example is an image I couldn't help but wonder.

Comment: The essence of the problem is that each of these sections will express a percentage ratio of indicators and I do not quite understand how this can be implemented. Do you happen to know how to indent and round off a chart?